# Melhor forma de comunicação do Aplicativo com o Servidor

Tags: java, android, web-service, rest, socket

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que precisa se comunicar com o servidor (enviar e receber dados).
Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer essa troca de dados com segurança e performance? Através de REST/WEB SERVICE, Sockets, HTTP request ou alguma mais específica?

Obs: Me surpreende a forma com que o WhatsApp recebe informações, de forma instantanea e sem lentidão, seria esse um exemplo de Sockets?

Aguardo sugestão.

Answer (score 0):

Para connectar ao servidor, voce pode utilizar o Volley e a biblioteca OKHTTP. Para fazer pedidos simples voce pode ver no post [AQUI](https://felipenipo.wordpress.com/2014/10/17/http-em-android-com-volley/)

No caso do Whatsapp que voce falou arriscaria dizendo que no servidor deles  que eles tem uma implementacao do Google Cloud Messaging(GCM). O GCM funciona de forma que sempre que o utilizador instala e corre a aplicacao pela primeira vez, registra-se ao servidor do google e o servidor retorna uma chave que ira identificar a aplicacao naquele dispositivo, de seguida a app envia essa chave para o servidor(neste caso o do whatsapp) e guarda no banco associado ao utilizador logado. Sempre que um outro utilizador decide mandar uma mensagem para este utilizador, ele vai a tabela que tem o registro da chave associada ao utilizador e este mesmo servidor envia uma mensagem ao GCM com a chave e a mensagem e o google faz o deliver da informacao assim que o utilizador ou app estiver disponivel.

Mais sobre o assunto vejam o link [AQUI](https://dariomungoi.wordpress.com/2014/09/)